# How to set Fragment on top of GLSurfaceView that has setZOrderOnTop set to true

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, surfaceview, glsurfaceview

I have a GLSurfaceView that has the setZOrderOnTop set to true (otherwise the GLSurfaceView does not display the content correctly). I need to display a Fragment on top of this view but it seems an impossible task. I've tried everything present on the internet and nothing works.. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The SurfaceView's surface is on a separate layer from all of the View UI.  By default, it's below the View layer, but if you use `setZOrderOnTop()` then it appears on top of everything.

You didn't say what sort of layout you're trying to get, but it's likely that a [TextureView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html) will work better, as those are rendered on the View layer.

You can use GLES to render to a TextureView, but you won't have the EGL setup or thread handling that GLSurfaceView provides.  See [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika) for examples (e.g. "Simple GL in TextureView").

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I will try your suggestion and see how it goes

Comment: Feels like you are having to repeat this in one form or another every week :).